# Запрос происходит очень долго php, mysql

Tags: php, mysql

при таком коде скрипт очень долго грузится (4,5 секунд)

```
$findresdecoder = mysqli_query($cfg->get_connection(),"SELECT * FROM `harddecoder` WHERE `vk_id`='".$vkkid."' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 25");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($findresdecoder)){

                $hash=$row['hash'];
                
                $findhashdb = mysqli_query($cfg->get_connection(),"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `harddecoder` WHERE `hash`='".$hash."'");
                $findhash=mysqli_fetch_assoc($findhashdb);

}
```

А именно при строке

```
$findhashdb = mysqli_query($cfg->get_connection(),"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `harddecoder` WHERE `hash`='".$hash."'");
```

внутри while.
Есть ли способы этот код оптимизировать, и как?

Comment: Ээ, как насчёт подучить sql и сделать это одним запросом? Если я правильно понял тут нужно просто посчитать количество строк с одинаковыми хшами

Comment: Да, верно, но их 25 штук и для каждого нужно посчитать количество строк и вывести его

Comment: Всё ещё один запрос

Comment: И, кстати, sql injection ждет вас.  Не нужно vkkid добавлять в запрос конкатенацией

Comment: даже с учетом 26 запросов 4.5сек это многовато. индексы на vk_id и на hash  добавьте, если их нет.

Comment: @teran , спасибо большое, так как я еще учусь в этом всем разбираться и не все понятно, это очень сильно помогло, теперь результат 0,04 секунды, а можно ли добавлять индексы на все столбцы, повлияет это как-нибудь на работу?

Comment: конечно можно. повлияет - замедлит вставки в таблицу. в остальном ничем не поможет. Индексы добавляют на те поля, по которым проводят поиск. Индексы могут быть не по одному полю а по нескольким сразу. Порядок столбцов в индексе имеет значение. Первичный ключ всегда включается в индекс автоматически. лучше литературу почитать. теория там не то чтобы большая, но в комментарий или ответ не уместить

Answer (score 0):

1. Сделать 1им запросом....
2. Расставить индекс на harddecoder.hash

```
<?php
$in = ["hash1", "hash2", "hash3"];
$join = '("' . join($in, '","') . '")'

$SQL = <<< END_SQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `harddecoder`
WHERE `hash` IN $join
GROUP BY `hash`
END_SQL;
```

**Добавлено чуток спустя:**

Вот полный пример как всё собрать, с помощью 1 запроса на примере TryIt editor https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_asc

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(a.Country) as "CountTotal"
FROM
    (SELECT c.Country FROM Customers as "c" ORDER BY c.PostalCode DESC LIMIT 25) as "a"
GROUP BY a.Country
ORDER BY CountTotal DESC
```